lower bound for absolute value of determinant of a square matrix
I want to have a lower bound for the absolute value of the determinant of a general non-singular real square matrix. Of course the trivial 0 is not what I want. However, any loose bound suffices (anything larger than zero). I have searched and seemingly lower bounds on determinant are not available that much. For an upper bound, I know the Hadamard's and a some others. Please note that I do not want to calculate the matrix eigenvalues or singular values (or also matrix inverse) for the bound, cause they add to the computational effort. A lower bound based on norms or less computationally costly operations is desired. The type of matrices I am talking about, unfortunately, do not have any special properties (such as being diagonally dominant or so). I also studied the paper: "A determinantal lower bound, Linear Algebra and its Applications 326 (2001) 151–159" but it also requires some eigenvalue computations.
Thank you very much

Here's a lower bound based on norms: $\left( \min_{x \in S^{n-1}} | Ax | \right)^n$. Presumably that's not what you want, either. Unless you tell us something about the class of matrix, and the kinds of norms you're interested in, this isn't really a math question -- it's a guessing game.

@JohnHughes Thank you for your reply. The matrices I am dealing with are state matrices of linear time-invariant dynamical systems and they are real ($\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$). That is all. I just want a lower bound for the abs of the determinant of the matrix that is computationally friendly. So, the spectral norm (norm 2) for example is not good for me.

I take it that "computationally friendly" means "not $O(n^3)$". Would $O(n^{2.5})$ be good? $O(n^2 \log n)$?  I don't hold out much hope here, but maybe someone will surprise us.

@JohnHughes  Yes, $O(n^{2.5})$ seems better. Could you suggest something? I thought about a way using Gershgorin disks, however it is only good if the matrix is diagonally dominant.

Nah...I got nothin' . I was merely trying to help you convert your question into one specific enough to make someone think it's worth answering. (My "not holding out hope" wasn't because I doubt such bounds exist, although I've never seen any ... it was because I didn't think anyone would invest much in a question like this, based on my years with MSE.
